# Yet Another Xamarin Forms Pinch Zoom

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I know nothing about Xamarin, but I inherited a project.  The request is to pinch and zoom on one of the forms.  I followed a tutorial on pinch and zoom on an image, and that worked out fine.  However I do not seem to be able to apply to a whole page.  I am using the default PinchToZoomContainer from the Xamarin dev site.

Here is how I am implementing it.

Here is where the PinchZoomContainer lives
[image: screen shot of project]

I think this exposing the name space

xmlns:utilites="clr-namespace:MSTCEvents.Views.Utilities"

And this is how I think it needs to be applied.

```
 <ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid>
        
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <controls:Header Grid.Row="0"/>
        <controls:CustomScrollView Grid.Row="1">
            <utilites:PinchZoomContainer>
                <utilites:PinchZoomContainer.Content>
```

a bunch of StackLayouts follow then

```
      </utilites:PinchZoomContainer.Content>
    </utilites:PinchZoomContainer>
 </controls:CustomScrollView>
```

Just to see if I could get something simple to work I tried to add a final stacklayout at the end and just apply the container there, with no luck.

```
                    <StackLayout>
                        <utilites:PinchZoomContainer>
                            <utilites:PinchZoomContainer.Content>
                                <Image Source="Images/mstcLogo.jpg" />
                            </utilites:PinchZoomContainer.Content>
                        </utilites:PinchZoomContainer>
                    </StackLayout>
```

I am using Ctrl Left Mouse Click to simulate the gestures on an emulator.

cheers

Comment: you are trying to apply Pinch/Zoom to content that is NOT an image?

Comment: Yes, as I understand it they want the whole page to zoom.  Labels, text areas, buttons, etc  Is that even possible?

Comment: I'm sure there is a way to do it, but I don't think the PinchToZoomContainer is designed to work with anything besides images.

Comment: hmm Ok Thanks a bunch.  At least I am not losing my mind

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple test about it: wrap the stacklayout inside the PinchToZoomContainer,and add the pinchGesture on page's GestureRecognizers,code as following:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
<local:PinchToZoomContainer>
<StackLayout>
<Label Text="This is a label" ></Label>
<Grid Padding="20">
<Image Source="pic.PNG" />
</Grid>
<Label Text="This is a label" ></Label>
</StackLayout>
</local:PinchToZoomContainer>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

**codebehind:**

```
      var pinchGesture = new PinchGestureRecognizer(); 
    pinchGesture.PinchUpdated += (s, e) => { // Handle the pinch }; 

GestureRecognizers.Add(pinchGesture);
```